# php - why does casting false to an array not result in empty array

Tags: php

I have a method return type can either be an array of things or false.

I am therefore casting the result to an array to try to ensure my code doesnt need to check for false or array.

But, php is casting false to an array containing 1 element: false:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

WHY!

Is there a way to achieve this without the if statement?

i.e.

```
if ($returnValue === false) {
    return array();
} else {
    return $returnValue;
}
```

Comment: "*the if statement*. What if statement?

Comment: How are you doing the casting?

Comment: the casting is like (array)$returnValue

Answer (score 6):

Working as designed. [The manual specifies](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting) :

> For any of the types: `integer`, `float`, `string`, `boolean` and `resource`, converting a value to an array results in an array with a single element with index zero and the value of the scalar which was converted. In other words, `(array)$scalarValue` is exactly the same as `array($scalarValue)`.

Can't you simply use a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)?

```
return (is_array($returnValue) ? $returnValue : array());
```

Comment: +1 it should always be like that, whenever you expect an array as the return type.

Comment: Indeed.  You might have an array of Booleans.  Also worth noting that casting `null` to an array gives an empty array, not `null`, but which will evaluate to `false` in a loose conditional (with `==` rather than `===`, or without a comparison operator).